# Extending NHibernate to support custom joins for fulltext

Tags: sql-server, nhibernate, full-text-search

We have a .NET application heavily based on a NHibernate driven data access layer using both Criteria and QueryOver APIs to query a SQL Server 2008 database.
The requirement is to introduce some query filters based on native Microsoft SQL Server FullText capabilities with ranking.

Translating this to SQL we have something like this.

```
SELECT * FROM entities
INNER JOIN FREETEXTTABLE(entities, ft_column, "some ft query") ft_tbl
  ON entities.Id = ft_tbl.[KEY]
ORDER BY ft_tbl.[RANK] DESC
```

I stress that we need to use the FREETEXT **table function**, not the FREETEXT scalar one here.

We cannot use a subquery criterion, because we need to do pagination of results ordered by rank.

Now, how can I extend NHibernate to introduce support for such a custom join in Criteria and QueryOver APIs?

I've digged into the NHibernate sources finding the best extension point for this, as already done in the past but this time I did not succeed, so I turn to the NHibernate experts out there.

Thank you in advance.